# What is the most stable and Pythonic cross-platform way to separate a string of path,filename,ext into three separate variables?

Tags: python, string, filenames, filepath, file-extension

I'm trying to separate a string into three variables where `C:\Example\readme.txt` could be read as `C:\Example`, `readme`, and `.txt` for the sake of a script I'm writing. It may be deployed in both Windows and Unix environments and may deal with both Windows or Unix paths, so I need to find a way that complies to both standards; I've read about several functions that achieve similar to this, but I'm looking for some input on how to best handle the single string inside a function.

*Note, I'm running IronPython 2.6 in this environment, and I'm not sure if that varies so greatly with standard Python 2.7 that I would need to adapt my usage.

EDIT: I'm aware of using `os.path.splitext` to get the extension from the filename, but finding a platform-independent way to get both the path and the filename (which I later use `splitext` on) is what boggles me.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I haven't tried anything yet. I'm new to programming and I've wasted so much time trying to figure things out myself (only to redo it later for a much better way) that I'm trying to save time by claiming defeat and talking to people who actually know what they're talking about.

Comment: This is not a defeat, merely a difficult learning process (or a steep learning curve, if you like). So don't despair :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `os.path` module, which has [several versions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) depending on the OS that you're running. But importing `os.path` should always give you *the right one*. If you can you could check the OS you're using manually:

```
import platform
platform.platform()
```

and then import the appropriate path toolkit from `os`. But it sure is a lot easier to just go `import os.path`.

So what would be of interest to you is:

```
os.path.basename(path) # To get the name of the file with extension.
os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0] # To get just the name.
os.path.dirname(path) # To get the directory leading to the file.
```

Hope this helps.

**CAVEAT:** I give no guarantee this is *THE* best way to do it.

Comment: I've read some interesting hiccups can occur using `basename`, due to the shaky handling of back/forward slashes between UNIX and Windows systems; However, I think I'll leave that to the people above me who will use the code. I'll take your answer, because the simple implementation will do more for the higher-ups than a comprehensive one.

Comment: Can always write a short script and test it on both Windows and Unix machines. Will save you time to do it now that to discover some errors somewhere further down the line.

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this, but I'm a new intern with no access to a machine outside of my own Windows-based one. It's frustrating. Also, I'm having trouble with your code. Running `basename` on a string returns the *entire* string, where running `dirname` returns a blank. Do you know why this is?

Comment: What's the string that you run it on? Try it with output from `os.getcwd`. I know the joys, been there and done that ;) Just finished the periods of frustrating internships myself. I can probably do it for you on my Ubuntu later today.

Comment: I've been running all of my little tests in Codecademy Labs because it's fast and familiar; But geunning `os.getcwd()` as well as `print "Testing: " + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(stg))` both return `"/sandbox"`... and I figure that's Codecademy's doing.

Comment: Do you have python on your PC? If not, get it here:
http://python.org/download/ (the above code works for 2.7, should probably be fine for 3.x too but no guarantees).
Then run the script in IDLE and see what comes out.

Comment: I'm currently running IronPython 2.6 and Python 2.7 on my computer; I just like using the codecademy one because I know it better.

After trying my local Python 2.7, I've found both Basename and Dirname work as described. It's weird that it won't work on Codecademy, but that's probably because it's a hosted activity in a server...

Comment: Perhaps, who knows? Glad they work because I was beginning to wonder :)

Comment: @JWarner112 _"I've read some interesting hiccups can occur using basename, due to the shaky handling of back/forward slashes between UNIX and Windows systems"_ I wonder what you mean. When I read the answer of Aleksander, I find it better than mine, and I don't see what flaw it could have, except what you are evoking, but I don"t know the precise cases you evoke. Could you explain, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You want `os.path.split` + `os.path.splitext`. Please take some time reading the doc next time, it would have been *waaaayyyy* faster than posting here.

Comment: I've been reading. The problem is that I'm too new and literally /everything/ is implicit when I dive into a new thing. The documentation on `os.path.split` does not specify a platform. Devising, writing, and implementing tests to make sure everything is in place would take hours. Asking you nice people is my best way of learning in any time-efficient scope, because you know what you're talking about about I most certainly do not.

Comment: @JWarner112: the FineManual(tm) for `os.path` clearly states that "Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths.". There are also some notes about portability in the `os` package's doc.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code to take account of the ChrisP's remark:

```
import re
from os.path import sep
rs = re.escape(sep)

basepat = ('(/?.*?)(?=%s?[^%s]*\Z)'
           '(?:%s([^.]*)(\.[^.]+)?)?\Z')

print '* On a Windows platform'
sep = '\\'
print 'sep: %s  repr(s): %r' % (sep,sep)
print 'rs = re.escape(sep)'
rs = re.escape(sep)
print 'rs: %s   repr(rs): %r' % (rs,rs)
rgx = re.compile(basepat % (rs,rs,rs))
for fn in (r'C:\Example\readme.txt',
           r'C:\Example\.txt',
           r'C:\Example\readme',
           'C:\Example\\readme\\',
           'C:\Example\\rod\pl\\',
           'C:\Example\\rod\p2',
           r'C:\Egz\rod\pl\zu.pdf',
           'C:\Example\\',
           'C:\Example',
           'C:\\'):
    m = rgx.match(fn)
    if m:  print '%-21s  %r' %(fn,m.groups(''))
    else:  print fn
print

print '\n* On a Linux platform'
sep = '/'
print 'sep: %s  repr(s): %r' % (sep,sep)
print 'rs = re.escape(sep)'
rs = re.escape(sep)
print 'rs: %s   repr(rs): %r' % (rs,rs)
rgx = re.compile(basepat % (rs,rs,rs))
for fn in ('/this/is/a/unix/folder.txt',
           '/this/is/a/unix/.txt',
           '/this/is/a/unix/folder',
           '/this/is/a/unix/folder/',
           '/this/', 
           '/this'):
    m = rgx.match(fn)
    if m:  print '%-21s  %r' %(fn,m.groups(''))
    else:  print fn
```

result

```
* On a Windows platform
sep: \  repr(s): '\\'
rs = re.escape(sep)
rs: \\   repr(rs): '\\\\'
C:\Example\readme.txt  ('C:\\Example', 'readme', '.txt')
C:\Example\.txt        ('C:\\Example', '', '.txt')
C:\Example\readme      ('C:\\Example', 'readme', '')
C:\Example\readme\     ('C:\\Example\\readme', '', '')
C:\Example\rod\pl\     ('C:\\Example\\rod\\pl', '', '')
C:\Example\rod\p2      ('C:\\Example\\rod', 'p2', '')
C:\Egz\rod\pl\zu.pdf   ('C:\\Egz\\rod\\pl', 'zu', '.pdf')
C:\Example\            ('C:\\Example', '', '')
C:\Example             ('C:', 'Example', '')
C:\                    ('C:', '', '')


* On a Linux platform
sep: /  repr(s): '/'
rs = re.escape(sep)
rs: \/   repr(rs): '\\/'
/this/is/a/unix/folder.txt  ('/this/is/a/unix', 'folder', '.txt')
/this/is/a/unix/.txt   ('/this/is/a/unix', '', '.txt')
/this/is/a/unix/folder  ('/this/is/a/unix', 'folder', '')
/this/is/a/unix/folder/  ('/this/is/a/unix/folder', '', '')
/this/                 ('/this', '', '')
/this                  ('/this', '', '')
```

`basepat` is the same for the two cases, Windos or Linux platform in the above code. Then the real code will be:

```
import re
from os.path import sep
rs = re.escape(sep)
rgx = re.compile('(/?.*?)(?=%s?[^%s]*\Z)'
                 '(?:%s([^.]*)(\.[^.]+)?)?\Z'
                 % (rs,rs,rs))
etc...
```

.

### #

The regex pattern `'(.*)\\\\([^.\\\\]*)(\.[^.]+)?\Z'` can be read more easily under this form:

```
('(.*)'
 '\\\\'
 '([^.\\\\]*)'
 '(\.[^.]+)?'
 '\Z')
```

1)
`(.+)` means "as much characters as possible, this succession of character must be kept as group(1)"
`+` is a quantifier. Without a `?` after it, it is a greedy quantifier -> "as much as possible..."
Parentheses are the symbols that determine the matching succession of characters to be kept in a group. As these parens are the first in the pattern, the group will be numbered 1.
Note that the mandatory presence of a string char `\` in the analyzed text, expressed by `\\\\` has for consequence that the greediness of `.*` is limited: in fact the regex motor stops in front of the lmast `\` in the text to keep the possibility of the compiled regex to match, which wouldn't be the case if `.+` was greedily matching the whole analysed string.

2)
`\\\\` : when `re.compile()` sees this series, it interprets it as "a string character \ must be in the analysed string at this position" .
The reason why it is needed to represent the string character `\` with 4 string characters `\` in the string representing a regex pattern is relatively hard to understand.
The `re.compile()` function must be feeded with regex symbols. But the only way we have to specify symbols to `re.compile()` is to pass string of characters to it as argument. That's why I wrote **string representing a regex pattern** just above here. Because `re.compile()` doesn't directly treat a string, it compiles a succession of symbols that it first obtains from interpretation of the string pattern.
For common characters like `k` or `;`, it is simple: the symbol expressing `k` is simply represented by the string character `k`, and for `;` it's `;`.
For special characters like `*`,`+`,`?`etc that have special meaning for the regex motor, their expression must use the special character `\` : so `\.` will express "a dot", `\?` will express "a question mark", etc.
But for the `\` string character, it has itself a special meaning inside a string: it escapes the following character. For example in "\"", the string char `\` escapes the `"` char, in order that there is no error.
And the problem is that string char `\` escapes itself. Then, if one would write `aaa\\bbb` as a regex pattern, the double backslash will be interpreted as expressing a string char `\`, not a regex symbolisation of the string char `\`.
Then, `\\` being inefficient to symbolize string char `\`, this symbolization is done with 4 string chars : `\\\\`

3)
`[a4:]` means "ONE character that can be either `a` or `4` or `:`"
`[^a4:]` means "any character, except one of the three chars `a`,`4` and `:`
Then `[^.\\\\]*` means "any character, except a dot and the char `\`" and the star means " the preceding defined character can be repeated or absent.
Note that a dot between brackets losses its special meaning, there's no need to escape it.
As this is between parens, the succession of characters matched by `[^a4:]` will be kept in a second group object.

5)
`(\.[^.]+)?` means "a dot followed by a succession of characters that can be any of the existing characters except the dot". Here the dot in the pattern  must be escaped to express a dot symbol that will mean only "a dot char" and not "every character".
As there is `+`, the dot, if present in the analyzed text, MUST be followed by at least one char.
But the presence of the special meaningful character `?` after the whole means that this succession **dot and at least one more char different of a dot** can be absent.

6)
`\Z` expresses the very end of a string. This symbol expresses that every matching must concern the whole analyzed string, until its very end; the matching won't be accepted to stop before the end.

.

#### EDIT

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('(/?.*?)(?=[\\\\/]?[^\\\\/]*\Z)'
                 '(?:[\\\\/]([^.]*)(\.[^.]+)?)?\Z')

for fn in ('C:\\Example\\readme.txt',
           'C:\\Example\\.txt',
           'C:\\Example\\readme',
           'C:\\Example\\readme\\',
           'C:\\Example\\rod\pl\\',
           'C:\\Example\\rod\p2',
           'C:\\Egz\\rod\\pl\\zu.pdf',
           'C:\\Example\\',
           'C:\\Example',
           'C:\\',
           '/this/is/a/unix/folder.txt',
           '/this/is/a/unix/.txt',
           '/this/is/a/unix/folder',
           '/this/is/a/unix/folder/',
           '/this/', 
           '/this',
           '\\machine\\share\\folder',
           'c:/folder\folder2',
           'c:\\folder\\..\\folder2',
           'c:\\folder\\..\\fofo2.txt',
           'c:\\folder\\..\\ki/fofo2.txt'):
    m = rgx.match(fn)
    if m:  print '%-26s  %r' %(fn,m.groups(''))
    else:  print fn,'   ***No match***'
```

result

```
C:\Example\readme.txt       ('C:\\Example', 'readme', '.txt')
C:\Example\.txt             ('C:\\Example', '', '.txt')
C:\Example\readme           ('C:\\Example', 'readme', '')
C:\Example\readme\          ('C:\\Example\\readme', '', '')
C:\Example\rod\pl\          ('C:\\Example\\rod\\pl', '', '')
C:\Example\rod\p2           ('C:\\Example\\rod', 'p2', '')
C:\Egz\rod\pl\zu.pdf        ('C:\\Egz\\rod\\pl', 'zu', '.pdf')
C:\Example\                 ('C:\\Example', '', '')
C:\Example                  ('C:', 'Example', '')
C:\                         ('C:', '', '')
/this/is/a/unix/folder.txt  ('/this/is/a/unix', 'folder', '.txt')
/this/is/a/unix/.txt        ('/this/is/a/unix', '', '.txt')
/this/is/a/unix/folder      ('/this/is/a/unix', 'folder', '')
/this/is/a/unix/folder/     ('/this/is/a/unix/folder', '', '')
/this/                      ('/this', '', '')
/this                       ('/this', '', '')
\machine\share\folder       ('\\machine\\share', 'folder', '')
c:/folderolder2            ('c:', 'folder\x0colder2', '')
c:\folder\..\folder2        ('c:\\folder\\..', 'folder2', '')
c:\folder\..\fofo2.txt      ('c:\\folder\\..', 'fofo2', '.txt')
c:\folder\..\ki/fofo2.txt   ('c:\\folder\\..\\ki', 'fofo2', '.txt')
```

Comment: I like this post for what it seems to be able to do, however not only is it above my level but it's inapplicable to me specifically. Sadly, the script I'm working on gets handled through a middle-man interpreter and some of these uses of syntax are shaky through it. For instance, it won't do r'<string>' for some infuriating reason. Thank you, though!

Comment: You must remark that I used raw strings ``r'blabla'`` only for the definitions of the files names, not for the pattern ``'(.*)\\\\([^.\\\\]*)(\.[^.]+)?\Z'`` of the regex. In fact , this raw string notation isn't mandatory in the solution, I used it only for the definitions of the filenames, that can also be written ``('C:\\Example\\readme.txt','C:\\Example\\.txt',...etc``. And in your code, the filenames will come already defined, you won't have to define them with the help of raw string

Comment: @ChrisP What kind of errors with Unix paths, please ? I don't know very well the Linux domain.

Comment: I admit also that I've never used `re` and have less than no idea what the line `rgx = re.compile('(.*)\\\\([^.\\\\]*)(\.[^.]+)?\Z')` means, even if it's not necessary* in the solution. I want to understand it, I just have no concept what what it means in real english. And I'm not sure what you mean by "the filenames come already defined", because if I haven't differentiated between filename and filepath, how would the system know how to define it?

Comment: Unix paths don't follow the same structure as Windows path: first, the separator isn't \, it's `/`. Second, they don't have the concept of drive: everything is a folder. It looks like: `/this/is/a/unix/folder`.

Comment: @ChrisP Knowing what you just said is what lead me to asking this question. My workplace implements both Windows and Linux systems everywhere and I just want those code to be able to work on both OSes.

Comment: Then I'd follow @Aleksander Lidtke's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18446221/2698119), it seems like a better cross-platform option.

Comment: @JWarner112 Please, see my edit and the explanation of the regex pattern you whished.

Comment: @ChrisP I completely rewrote my answer after your comment. Please, say me what you think about it.

Comment: That's indeed better, and I like how you took the time to explain the various parts of your regexp. However  there are situations your code won't handle on Windows: path on a network (`\\machine\share\folder`) or a mix between slashes and backslashes (`c:/folder\folder2`). Note that relative paths (`c:\folder\..\folder2`), and the long path prefix (`\\?\c:\very_long_folder`) for when the path is longer than 255, will be supported. Paths on Windows are not as simple as they appear.. Using @Aleksander Lidtke's answer will avoid having to deal with all this by hand.

Comment: @ChrisP And now ? Edited my answer. Just for fun, I don't think my code will be better than Aleksander's answer. Except that OP evoked _"hiccups in using basename"_ sic

Comment: You're tenacious :) You're still missing c:file.txt. See [the MSDN article on file naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) for all the possible ways paths can be written on Windows. Also, I ran your code against `os.path`, and path `/this` on Unix should yield a base folder of `/`, and a file name of `this`.

Comment: @ChrisP Tenacious, but well... I'll presently drop the problem because I'm not enough aware of the variations of files names in Windows, and in Linux too. It would take me too long to study your linked page. It's an interesting one, thank you for having led me to it. I will read it studiously some time and maybe I will come back to this problem in the future. I think Aleksander's answer is the best and presently sufficient

Comment: I agree with you both-- This is still a bit above me but with some time working with Regexp I could get it. I appreciate you going through so much effort to give a good answer, if I could do multiple upvotes I would!